# почему не импортируется swiper в svelte?

Tags: swiper, svelte

При импортировании swiper выдает ошибку: **Failed to route the request:  is not a valid SSR component. You may need to review your build config to ensure that dependencies are compiled, rather than imported as pre-compiled modules**
Версия swiper: 6.7.5

Comment: Как насчёт `if(process.browser === true)`?

Comment: Или так https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-environment-browser